# AnimationDrawable memory crash

Tags: java, android, animation

I'd like to make an animation in my application. But when I add the frames (number of frames are between 30 and 150) programmatically because sometimes I want to ignore a set of frames. The app crashes with the exception Bitmap exceeds VM bugdet. How can I avoid that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you add the frames from resource or you extract a gif image programmatically ??

Comment: @Caroline Could you show us the code where you add the frames?

Comment: Voted down because there's no effort, from a long time, by the questioner in cooperating to come up with an answer. Basically this question seems to be abandoned.